# JavaMail Output stops right after Boundary

Tags: java, osgi, jakarta-mail

at the moment I'm encountering a problem which I really don't understand. I have a class inside a OSGI-Plugin, which also contains javax.mail-1.6.2.jar as bundled classpath inside the osgi-plugins lib folder. When I run the code with a simple main-method on my machine, everything works. The mail contains all parts and end correct. But when I run the plugin inside our third-party application, JavaMail suddenly stops the output after the first boudary. No exception is raised, no logmessage,it just ends output and continues.

```
Date: Sun, 13 Jun 2021 10:05:26 +0200 (CEST)
From: noreply@localhost.com
Reply-To: noreply@localhost.com
To: test@nodomain.com
Message-ID: <126209092.01623571526344.JavaMail.LOCALHOST$@LOCALHOST>
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?#web#_[TEST]=C2=A0Tesfall_zu_?=
 =?utf-8?Q?javamail_(test@nodomain.com)?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_0_185595348.1623571526344"
```

Thats it. It's just empty.

I already reduced the error sources, the output is the same (truncated) mail, when I save it. So its not the smtp-gateway or any smtp setting. And now I don't have any idea left, where to look next. I cannot debug the class on the third-party application, where it got loaded (Oracle Java SE 1.8 HotspotVM). Does anyone has any idea what could be a cause or how to narrow the cause?

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class DocumentToSmtp {

    public void process() throws Exception {
        String mailhost = "localhost";
        String port = "25";
        //Get SMTP output to logger
        final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final String utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();
        try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos, true, utf8)) {
            try {

                boolean authification = false;
                String prot = "smtp";
                Properties props = System.getProperties();
                if (mailhost != null) {
                    props.put("mail." + prot + ".host", mailhost);
                    props.put("mail." + prot + ".port", port);
                }
                props.put("mail." + prot + ".auth", authification);

                Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
                session.setDebug(true);
                session.setDebugOut(ps);

                MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

                String to = "test@nodomain.com";

                msg.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to, false));

                msg.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse("noreply@localhost.com", false));
                String subject = "#web# [TEST] Tesfall zu javamail (test@nodomain.com)";
                msg.setSubject(subject, "utf-8");

                String replyto = "noreply@localhost.com";`
                //originally the class contained multiple attachment as pdfs, but 
                List<MimeBodyPart> bodies = new ArrayList<>();

                // create and fill the first message part
                MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
                String text = "<!DOCTYPE html><html style=\"margin: 0; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px\">\r\n"
                        + "                 <head>\r\n"
                        + "           <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\r\n"
                        + "           <title>EMail</title>\r\n"
                        + "           <style type=\"text/css\">      /* common */\r\n"
                        + "               html, body {\r\n"
                        + "                 margin: 0;\r\n"
                        + "                 font-family: Arial;\r\n"
                        + "                 font-size: 14px;\r\n"
                        + "               }\r\n"
                        + "           </style>\r\n"
                        + "          </head>\r\n"
                        + "          <body style=\"margin: 0; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px\">\r\n Guten Tag!"
                        + "          </body>\r\n"
                        + "         </html>";

                mbp1.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");
                mbp1.setContent(text, "text/html; charset=utf-8"); //5
                bodies.add(mbp1);
                //add the parts to multi-part
                Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
                for (MimeBodyPart mbp : bodies) {
                    mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
                }
                msg.setContent(mp);
                msg.setSentDate(new Date());

                msg.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(new File("%TEMP%/test.eml")));
                Transport.send(msg);
            } finally {
                //Print logmessages. 
                String data = baos.toString(utf8);
                System.out.println(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OSGI Manifest

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.6
Created-By: 1.8.0_60-b27 (Oracle Corporation)
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 commons-codec-1.3.jar,
 commons-codec-1.9.jar,
 commons-lang3-3.3.1.jar,
 commons-httpclient-3.1.jar,
 commons-io-2.4.jar,
 commons-logging-1.1.3.jar, 
 javax.mail-1.6.2.jar
Bundle-Version: 42324
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: DocumentPlugins
Export-Service: de.documentworkflow.plugins.DocumentToSMTP
Import-Package: javax.activation,
 javax.crypto,
 javax.crypto.spec,
 javax.imageio,
 javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg,
 javax.imageio.stream,
 javax.net,
 javax.net.ssl,
 javax.xml.bind,
 javax.xml.bind.annotation,
 javax.xml.datatype,
 javax.xml.namespace,
 javax.xml.soap,
 javax.xml.transform,
 javax.xml.ws,
 javax.xml.ws.handler.soap
Embed-Dependency: commons-codec;scope=compile|runtime
Built-Date: 2020-06-13_07-07-54
Built-By: jenkins
Implementation-Version: 1706
Svn-Revision: 42323
Bundle-Vendor: test
Class-Path: posy-documentworkflow-interface-api-1
 .0.42323.jar commons-codec-1.9.jar trove-3.0.1.jar log4j-1.2.15.jar m
 ail-1.4.3.jar commons-net-3.3.jar jsch-0.1.53.jar guava-11.0.2.jar jd
 om.jar xsom.jar relaxngDatatype.jar javax.mail-1.6.2.jar
Require-Capability: osgi.ee
```

Best regards.

Comment: You must close the FileOutputStream to see the full content that is written to the stream in the file (or you can call flush if you do not want to close it yet).

Comment: Ah, yes. But it's not the cause of the message truncation. It is also happening to the smtp output, where no FileoutputStream is used

Comment: I have just copied your code with only one modification (instead of File output, I used System.out). And it works well, the whole message is there. I used com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.2 as dependency.